# Can i change below mysql query into elasticsearch dsl?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Query to find users revenue on 5 apr belongs to delhi and had done sign up event on 5th april.**

SELECT sum(revenue) FROM  `order` WHERE  `purchased_date` =  '2017-04-05 00:00:00' 
and userid in ( 
    select a.`userId` from user a, event b where a.userid=b.userid and a.city='delhi' and b.time='2017-04-05 00:00:00' and b.name='signup')

**Tables**

```
Order
id  purchasedDate        revenue  userId
  1  2017-04-05 00:00:00    30       1
  2  2017-04-06 00:00:00    30       1
  3  2017-04-05 00:00:00    80       2
  1  2017-04-06 00:00:00    70       2
  1  2017-04-05 00:00:00    60       3
  1  2017-04-06 00:00:00    40       3
  1  2017-04-07 00:00:00    50       3
  1  2017-04-07 00:00:00    30       3
User 
 id  city 
  1  delhi
  2  noida
  3  delhi
Event
 userid    name         time
  1      signup  2017-04-05 00:00:00
  2      signup  2017-04-05 00:00:00
  3      signup  2017-04-05 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah this is doable with elastic, but first of all you have to model your data from SQL table to document based no-sql data.

**Nested document approach**

1)You can model one instance of data as follows

```
{
    "purchasedDate": "2017-04-05",
    "revenue": 30,
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "city": "delhi",
        "event": [{
            "name": "signup",
            "time": "2017-04-05"
        }]
    }
}
```

For this data model you will also need to add supporting mappings

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "type_name": {
            "properties": {
                "purchasedDate": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "revenue": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "user": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "city": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "event": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "text"
                                },
                                "time": {
                                    "type": "date"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally you can fire the following query to get the desired results

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "revenue_sum": {
            "sum": {
                "field": "revenue"
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "purchasedDate": {
                        "value": "2017-04-05"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "term": {
                    "user.city": {
                        "value": "delhi"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "user.event",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "term": {
                                    "user.event.name": {
                                        "value": "signup"
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "term": {
                                    "user.event.time": {
                                        "value": "2017-04-05"
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

for furthur reading you can refer to following links

[mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)
[nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/nested.html)

**Parent Child approach**

Mappings

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "user": {
            "properties": {
                "city": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        },
        "event": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "user"
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "time": {
                    "type": "date"
                }
            }
        },
        "order": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "user"
            },
            "properties": {
                "purchasedDate": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "revenue": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index user, order and event documents

```
POST data_play2/user/1
{
  "city":"london"
}

POST data_play2/order/10?parent=1
{
  "purchasedDate":"2017-04-05",
  "revenue": 100
}

POST data_play2/event/1?parent=1
{
  "userid" : 1,
  "name" : "signup",
  "time" : "2017-04-05"
}
```

Query

```
    {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "revenue": {
            "children": {
                "type": "order"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "filtered_order": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "term": {
                                    "purchasedDate": {
                                        "value": "2017-04-05"
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "revenue_sum": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "revenue"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "city": {
                            "value": "london"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "has_child": {
                        "type": "order",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [{
                                    "term": {
                                        "purchasedDate": {
                                            "value": "2017-04-05"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "has_child": {
                        "type": "event",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [{
                                    "term": {
                                        "name": {
                                            "value": "signup"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "term": {
                                        "time": {
                                            "value": "2017-04-05"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Refer this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html) for furthur reading

Hope this helps

Comment: Can we solve it parent child relationship.Where user as a parent,order and event table is child of user and schema is same of all table.

Comment: yeah you can, parent-child will be better if you have large number of orders for each user as the size of the document will be in limit

Comment: can u please share query if i have user as as parent and order and event as a child and all have same schema as mysql.

Comment: sure, i will share in sometime after food

Comment: hey, i have updated my answer for parent-child approach, let me know

Comment: but if i added 
`POST hal/order/10?parent=1
{
  "purchasedDate":"2017-04-05T00:00:01",
  "revenue": 100
}
POST hal/order/11?parent=1
{
  "purchasedDate":"2017-04-06T00:00:01",
  "revenue": 100
}`

**answer is 200 but which is not true.**
please help to solve this.

Comment: i updated the query, my applogies, the reason why it was coming 200 was because the query returns the parent document that is user and then it was aggregating on the revenue field of all order for the matched user. That needs to filtered in the aggregation for the matched purchased date